# What is the range of $x$ satisfying the inequality $-x|x| > 4$ where $x$ is an integer?

Tags: absolute-value

The range according to me is x<-2. But I got to know that x>2 is also a possible solution. How can that be correct?

P.S. I know that this is a simple question. But I couldn't find any existing question in the forum related to this. If there exists one, please point me that way.

**Edit:**

[Mathway solver response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG7u5.png)

Comment: If $x$ is positive, then $|x| = x$, so $-x|x|$ is negative. In short, your solution is correct, and there is some problem with the other solution. For example, $ - 3 \times |3| = -9 < 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x>2$ is not a solution.

If $x>2$

$|x|>2$

$x|x|>4$

$-x|x|<4$

---

Your solution is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

The graph for function $$y=-x|x|$$ looks something like this[image] Here the red line represents $y=-x|x|$ and blue line represents $y=4$.

Therefore the integer values of $x$ such that $$-x|x|>4$$ are $x=-3,-4,-5,.....$

***Edit:-***

The horizontal line on which the points $0,1,2...etc$ are marked is called the x-axis. Similarly the vertical line on which the points $0,1,2...etc$ are marked is called the y-axis. The red line here is the graph of $y=-x|x|$. From the graph you can see as one moves towards $-ve$ x-axis, value of $y$ increases and $x$ decreases. As we approach $x=-2$, $y$ equals $4$. And as we move further towards $-ve$ x-axis, value of $y$ i.e. $-x|x|$ increases. Therefore the integer solutions of $x$ are $-3,-4,-5...$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess the graph was obtained from the Mathway solver .
The same solver gave this answer.
x>2 or x<-2.
There must be something wrong with the Mathway solver.

Comment: I have edited my answer so you might understand now

Comment: I do understand graphs :) What I was talking about is the site(https://www.mathway.com/prealgebra) from which you created the graph. The same site has given the answer for the above question as x>2 or x<-2 when solve for x is selected. That's what confused me in the first place. That was the reason for me putting this question.

Comment: This graph isn't from mathway.com but from the best graphing calculator Desmos. I would suggest you to graph these functions yourself. And In case you don't know to graph such functions, you can buy a book named "Play with Graphs by Amit m. Aggarwal ". You can search it on Amazon or any other site. I think this the best book to master graphs.